# Return 1x1 pixel image from AWS API Gateway, after proxy to Kinesis

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I am trying to have a AWS API Gateway endpoint in front of Kinesis, that can be used as a tracker pixel.  So there could be a  on an html page, and it would get back a 1x1 transparent image.

I've figured out how to do the integration request from API Gateway to Kinesis, transforming incoming params into a base64 encoded string and in the Kinesis json format.

But I am having really hard time how to return a 1x1 transparent png image from the API endpoint on success.

I've created a Method Response of 200 with a Response Body of content type "image/png" and Model empty.  Then I created a Integration Response with "Content Handling" of "Convert to Binary" and a mapping template of type "image/png" and value of "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAQAAAC1HAwCAAAAC0lEQVR42mNkYAAAAAYAAjCB0C8AAAAASUVORK5CYII=" which I got from http://png-pixel.com/

My hope was that the base64 encoded png image from the template would get converted to binary by API Gateway and returned, along with content type image/png

Instead I am having a "Execution failed due to configuration error: Unable to transform response" error in my API Gateway logs and the api returns 500 code and application/json content type.

I have also added image/png to the Binary Media Types on the Stage settings.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I could do this by:

1. Set Content-Type to "imaga/png" in lambda
2. Add "text/html" in the mapping template of Integration response.

```
#set($context.responseOverride.header.Content-Type = $input.path('$').header.Content-Type)
$input.path('$').body
```

3. Set Response Body of content type "text/html" and Model empty.

Comment: Yes, the problem is I am trying to do this in ApiGateway without Lambda back end.  My ApiGateway API just puts a message on a Kinesis stream.  I don't have Lambda involved at all.

Comment: @Michael did you ever find a way to do this? 
I made the mistake of using an API Gateway HTTP API and it's not robust enough for this type of operation. So I'm planning to move to a REST API.

I'm hoping this is actually possible, instead of having a lambda as the proxy service

Comment: @howdy_miguel no, I never got it to work, though that doesn't mean its not possible, also that was over 2 years ago, API Gateway may have added features since then

Comment: Thanks for the follow up. I'm sure API Gateway REST API had support for it, but HTTP API has less features, so I couldn't find a way to map the response to return a 1x1 pixel image.

But! I did find another solution, for anyone that's in this situation. I mapped the statusCode 200 to 204 (No Content). Which has the same behavior as a placeholder pixel.